# Export CSV without col.names

Tags: sqlite, r, csv

I need to take a `data.frame` and export it to a CSV file (or something else, but CSV seemed like the easiest well-formed format) so I can import it into an SQLite database.

However, it looks like `write.csv()` requires that I write a header line, and SQLite's `.import` command requires that I **don't** have a header line.  So that's a bit of a mismatch.

Here's what happens if I try to omit the header line:

```
> write.csv(mydf, "/tmp/mydf.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F)
Warning message:
In write.csv(mydf, "/tmp/mydf.csv", row.names = F, col.names = F) :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
```

I have to wonder why it's enforcing that in the first place - the manual says *"These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change `append`, `col.names`, `sep`, `dec` or `qmethod` are ignored, with a warning."*  But I know of nothing in the spec or elsewhere requiring column names - indeed, most tools (Excel, etc.) don't treat them specially.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

*If you can't beat 'em, join 'em.*

If you switch to `write.table()` (which `write.csv()` calls anyway) you're golden:

```
R> write.table(trees, file="/tmp/trees.csv", 
+              row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
R> system("head /tmp/trees.csv")
8.3,70,10.3
8.6,65,10.3
8.8,63,10.2
10.5,72,16.4
10.7,81,18.8
10.8,83,19.7
11,66,15.6
11,75,18.2
11.1,80,22.6
11.2,75,19.9
R>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This kind of makes me wonder whether `write.csv()` is really dealing with all the idiosyncrasies of the CSV format, but maybe I'll worry about that another day.

Comment: @KenWilliams I wondered the same when I saw this kind of API design. To trap users first then send warnings to them isn't a very friendly way to enforce a certain convention.

Answer (score 10):

You can directly import it into SQLite.  The following imports the built in data frame `BOD` into the SQLite database `my.db` (creating `my.db` if it does not already exist).

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "my.db")
dbWriteTable(con, "BOD", BOD, row.names = FALSE)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use write.table() instead like so:

```
write.table(mydf, "/tmp/mydf.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=",")
```